# Moving files in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this line of code to move files and folders over a certain age to another folder

But it doesnt work, I run it but it just goes back to a prompt

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\test | where-Object {$_.Creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)} | ForEach-Object { robocopy "c:\test" "c:\old" /Z /S  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: only robocopy

```
robocopy "c:\test" "c:\old"  /Z /S /MINAGE:yyyymmdd (or /MINAGE:<numbers of days>)
```

Comment: Will not work correctly, you need `$_.Fullname` instead of `"c:\test\$($_.name)"`

Comment: Christian thanks for your help, but that doesnt work either...its like the robocopy part isnt running. I tried running the Robocopy from the cmd line and that works fine on its own

Comment: Ocaso, do you mean like this "c:\test\$_.Fullname)" ?

Comment: First, do you really need Robocopy? Second, do you really want to move folders created before a certain date? The folders might contain newer files? Or do you really just want to move old files and retain the directory structure?

Comment: Not sure, but what happens, when you e.g. have 2 files named `foo.bar`, one older than 6 months and one younger than 6 months? IMHO ropocopy will copy both files, since it gets `foo.bar` as filename?

Comment: @OcasoProtal Really can exist two file with identical name in the same folder? In the question code the foreach before robocopy pipe only file older than 6 months ago.

Comment: @Christian Beware of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`! ;) And as I understand robocopy the filename only acts as a "filter". (Of course there are not two files w/ identical name in the same directory)

Comment: @OcasoProtal Sure! The problem here is using robocopy as Jeffery say is not the best way mixing with powershell

Comment: @jeffrey I guess I dont necessarily need Robocopy, I just wanted a 1 line script that would do the job. Ideally I want to move old files and folders, but I realise this might not be exactly possible as you said.

Comment: @ Jeffrey I also tried this - foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem C:\test -Recurse) { if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddMonths(-6))) { Copy-Item $.FullName C:\old } }

Comment: @user1130264 "didn't work" means what? Nothing copied? Any error messages?

Comment: No error messages, I ran the line of code, and it just returns to command prompt in Powershell and nothing copied

Comment: I used this - robocopy c:\test c:\old /MINAGE:180 /S
 and it worked fine

Comment: @Christian - Interesting. I took out the Where-Object part, and it works fine - Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\test | ForEach-Object { robocopy "c:\test" "c:\old" $_.name /Z /S  }